# where does installer keeps its billboard files after installation in Windows

Tags: installshield, installshield-2013

I am Using InstallShield. I Have used some Billboards. After Installation Of the Program, When I go to Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs, and try to change my Program, BillBoard images still appear.

Want to know from which Directory is the Installer picking up the Billboard images now.

Found the same files in %TEMP%, but is there any other location also in which Installer keep Its support Files as %Temp% is just a temp location and can be any time deleted.

Hope, I am clear with My question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In InstallShield, the installer picks up the billboard files from SUPPORTDIR at Runtime. Although We keep the Billboard images in Billboard sub Section in InstallShield, but at runtime it extracts all support files like Billboard files together in SUPPORTDIR. We can Access these files using SUPPORTDIR as directory at runtime.

Install Shield Creates a Minimalistic cache of the installer at *FOLDER_APPLICATION\InstallShield Installation Information* and runs this at time of Uninstall and uses Billboards stored in data1.cab here, which can be used through SUPPORTDIR ^ nameofBIllboard

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to describe the problem you're trying to solve, because I suspect the answer won't help..

Assuming you have an MSI setup and the billboard images are stored in the conventional way, they are inside the cached MSI file in the \Windows\Installer directory. Maintenance and uninstall operations use the cached MSI file (so don't remove it) and go through its sequences in much the same way as during the install, and this includes extracting the images from the Binary table in the MSI file.